# php merge 2 array, 1 bidimensional and 1 monodimensial

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for my english
I try to say my problem with 2 array, one array is mono dimensional and another one is bidimensional.
I need send from form id language, value of textarea...like this:

```
<input type="text"  name="feature[]['<?php echo $row['idlang']?>']" >
<input type="text" name="val[]">
```

The javascript creates for each language put new input text, so if in database have 2 language this put 2 input text feature and 1 for value, if have 100 language this put 100 input text and always 1 for value, but we know that the features can be many.
The second dimension in feature is id language in this way have(feature[][]):
count array - id language - value of feature

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(9) "frequenza" } 
[1]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "frequency" } 
[2]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(10) "disco duro" } 
[3]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "hard disk" } 
[4]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(10) "processore" } 
[5]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(9) "processor" } }
```

instead in val[] array have:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> string(6) "3.2Ghz" 
[1]=> string(5) "500Gb" 
[2]=> string(8) "intel I7" }
```

how can i have this result in php from 2 input, 1 bidimensiol and 1 monodimensional?

```
 id language | feature name | feature value
     1       |  frequenza   |    3.2Ghz
     2       |  frequency   |    3.2Ghz
     1       | disco duro   |    500Gb
     2       |  hard disk   |    500Gb
     1       |  processore  |    intel I7
     2       |  processor   |    intel I7
```

I try(but nothing):

```
    foreach
      foreach
```

```
foreach
  foreach
    foreach
```

```
foreach
  foreach
foreach
```

```
foreach
foreach
  foreach
```

all this because it is one insert in field json.
Thank you!!

Comment: Can you change the way the javascript generates the structure? Right now there seems to be no correlation between the two arrays. Unless you know the exact number of elements and you want to hard code it the easiest way would be to change the data structure.

Comment: hmm.. here is no relationship key between this two arrays, I guess your first array should be slightly modified somethig like that: array(3){[0]=>array(2){[1]=>string(..)"frequenza", [2]=>string(..)"frequency"}, [1]=>array(2){[1]=>string(..)"disco duro",[2]=>string(..)"hard disk"}...) etc.. In this case you can process your data with more simple/correct way.

Comment: Side note: correct translation for “hard disk” is “disco rigido”, not “disco duro” :)

Comment: funsion3k: In italiano can say o write: disco duro but disco rigido too...I born in italy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to swap `[]` and `['<?php echo $row['idlang']?>']` in your form. You will have:

```
<input type="text"  name="feature[1][]" >
<input type="text"  name="feature[2][]" >
<input type="text" name="val[]">
<!-- 1 and 2 here are ids of a lang  -->
```

After that you will have 2 different `$_POST` arrays:

- one is `val`
- second is `feature`

You can iterate over them like:

```
foreach ($_POST['val'] as $k => $v) {
    // check if current val is not empty:
    if (!empty($v)) {
        // get according words from `features` 
        // they will have the same key ($k) under idlang key
        echo $_POST['feature'][1][$k];    // 1 is idlang
        echo $_POST['feature'][2][$k];    // 2 is idlang
        // after that you can do for example:
        // insert into db [1, $_POST['feature'][1][$k], $v]
        // insert into db [2, $_POST['feature'][2][$k], $v]
    }
}
```